# Event emit is not working from module component to Sibling of App component angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

Can you please help with a working example using stackblitz?

App Component

```
<app-sidebar (addNewEmployeeEmitted)="addNewEmployeeEmitted($event)"></app-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App Component related ts

```
addNewEmployeeEmitted(event:any) {
   alert('dfdfsd');
  }
```

Component A in another module

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addNewEmployee($event)">Submit</button>
```

Component A related ts

```
addNewEmployee(event:any) {
    this.addNewEmployeeEmitted.emit('hello parent');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Notes:

1- You have to decorate the emitter with @Output.

2- You have to initialize the emitter.

```
@Output() customEvent = new EventEmitter<`YourEmitterType`>();
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-huq4nv?file=src/app/app.component.ts